# Python: Configure logger with yaml to open logfile in write mode

Tags: python, logging, yaml

I have the following configuration of a logger in a the file loggingConfig.yml

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
    formatters:
        simple:
            format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

handlers:
    console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout

file_handler:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: simple
    filename: info.log
    encoding: utf8

loggers:
    my_module:
        level: ERROR
        handlers: [console]
        propagate: no

root:
     level: INFO
     handlers: [console, file_handler]
```

And the following python code:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

with open('loggingConfig.yml', 'rt') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('TestLogger')
```

This works fine, but now I would like to open the logfile in write mode and not in append mode.
I wasn't able to find any example which use a yaml file and opens the logfile in write mode.

I only found, that open in write mode can be done using the fileConfig

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```

and specify args in the logging.conf file:

```
args=('info.log', 'w')
```

Is there any way how I can do this using the yaml file or manipulating the config in the sourcecode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the following configuration:

```
file_handler:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: simple
    filename: info.log
    encoding: utf8
    mode: w
```

The default mode is 'a' which means *append* . More info on that [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html)